# In Corda, schema cannot be cast to net.corda.core.schemas.MappedSchema exception

Tags: corda

I am trying to create migration schemas for a CorDapp as per the instructions [here](http://docs.corda.r3.com/database-management.html#node-administrator-installing-a-cordapp-targeted-at-the-open-source-node). I am running the following command:

```
java -jar corda-tools-database-manager-3.1.jar 
--base-directory /opt/User
--create-migration-sql-for-cordapp fnolUseCase.state.FNOLSchema
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
-- 2018-08-22T13:29:23,145Z migration.tool.invoke - Creating database migration 
   files for schema: fnolUseCase.state.FNOLSchema into /opt/User/migration

Failed to create datasource.
Please check that the correct JDBC driver is installed in one of the following 
folders:
         - /opt/User/drivers

Caused By java.lang.ClassCastException: fnolUseCase.state.FNOLSchema cannot be cast 
to net.corda.core.schemas.MappedSchema
```

What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be having trouble locating your `fnolUseCase.state.FNOLSchema` class. Try dropping the schema name from the end of your command. This will cause a migration schema to be created for every schema in your application:

```
java -jar corda-tools-database-manager-3.1.jar 
--base-directory /opt/User
--create-migration-sql-for-cordapp fnolUseCase.state.FNOLSchema
```